# Add temp column for use in single mysql query as label

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query:

```
(
SELECT act_id, act_date, act_score
FROM actsWithScore
WHERE user_id =  '1'
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT act_id, vote_date, vote_score
FROM votes
WHERE user_voter =  '1'
)
ORDER BY  `act_date`
```

This works great and outputs similar to the following:

```
act_id      act_date                act_score
31          2014-03-06 07:08:12     NULL
30          2014-03-06 07:07:51     NULL
23          2014-03-06 06:52:54     1
21          2014-03-06 06:52:48     -1
12          2014-03-06 06:52:46     1
25          2014-03-06 06:52:42    -1
```

What I want to do is identify on the output which row is an act (from the `SELECT ... FROM actsWithScore` query), and which row is a vote (from the `SELECT ... FROM votes` query) like so:

```
act_id      act_date                act_score    decription
31          2014-03-06 07:08:12     NULL         act
30          2014-03-06 07:07:51     NULL         act
23          2014-03-06 06:52:54     1            vote
21          2014-03-06 06:52:48     -1           act
12          2014-03-06 06:52:46     1            vote
25          2014-03-06 06:52:42    -1            vote
```

Is this possible, and if so, how? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(
SELECT act_id, act_date, act_score, 'act' as description
FROM actsWithScore
WHERE user_id =  '1'
)
UNION ALL 
(

SELECT act_id, vote_date, vote_score, 'votes' as description
FROM votes
WHERE user_voter =  '1'
)
ORDER BY  `act_date`
```

Comment: Very quick on the buzzer! Thanks for the speedy response!

Answer (score 2):

Just do like this

```
(
SELECT act_id, act_date, act_score, 'Act' As description
FROM actsWithScore
WHERE user_id =  '1'
)
UNION ALL (

SELECT act_id, vote_date, vote_score, 'Vote'  As description

FROM votes
WHERE user_voter =  '1'
)
ORDER BY  `act_date`
```

Comment: You are both spot on, Thank you! Sorry but I gotta set the answer as the first correct responder when there are 2 identical answers, Deepak just pipped it